# Connections between sub modules wrong

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

My codes for Alu and Mux:

```
module alu(input logic [31:0]srca, srcb,
          input logic [2:0] alucontrol,
          output logic zero,
          output logic [31:0]aluout);

logic [31:0] addr, subr, sltr, Andr, Orr;
assign addr = srca + srcb;
assign subr = srca - srcb;
assign sltr = (srca < srcb) ? 1 : 0;
assign Andr = srca & srcb;
assign Orr = srca | srcb;
always_comb 
begin
case(alucontrol)
    3'b010: aluout = addr;
    3'b110: aluout = subr;
    3'b111: aluout = sltr;
    3'b000: aluout = Andr;
    3'b001: aluout = Orr;
    default: aluout = 32'bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
endcase
zero = (subr == 0) ?  1 : 0;
end
endmodule


module mux2#(parameter WIDTH = 8)
                (input logic [WIDTH-1:0] d0, d1,
                 input logic                 s,
                 output logic [WIDTH-1:0] y);
always_comb
begin
y = s?d1 : d0;
end
endmodule
```

and their instantiation under the same top module:

```
alu         alu(srca, srcb, alucontrol, aluout, zero);

mux2 #(32) resmux(aluout, readdata, memtoreg, result);
```

When I try to connect my 2-1Mux resmux with my alu, the aluout doesn't get connected to resmux

[aluout gets suspended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOxn4.png)

I could solve this by exchanging the order of aluout and zero, but could anybody explain why this happens and how to avoid? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of mechanisms for connecting ports in SystemVerilog. The mechanism you are using is *positional*. That means each signal connection has to go in the prescribed order that they appear in the module declaration of `alu`. The way your code is written, the signal `zero` in module `top` is connected to last port `aluout` declared in module `alu`.

SystemVerilog also has a *by_name* syntax `.portname(signal)`. You can list all your port connections in any order that way.

```
alu   alu(.srca(srca), .srcb(srcb), .alucontrol(alucontrol), .alu(aluout), .zero(zero));
```

When the signal name you are connecting matches the declared port name, you can just use `.portname`.

```
alu alu(.alucontrol, .aluout, .zero, .srca, .srcb);
```

And finally, if all the port names match the signal names, you can use a wildcard, `.*` as well as list exceptions explicitly

```
alu alu(.*, .zero(my_zero));
```